# Can not pass on property from one Component to another

Tags: reactjs

I trie to pass an Object from my Card Component to my FloatingActionButtons Component.
But i don't work i got the error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

If i pass just one attribute from the Object like name,abteilung,bereich,... then it works.
So, how can i pass the whole Object to the Component ?

Card.js

```
import FloatingButton from "./FloatingActionButtons";

export default function Card() {
const plan = new Plan("Max Mustermann", "woamen.jpg", "ITH/A", "IT", 13);

return (
     <FloatingButton azubi={plan}></FloatingButton>
   );
```

FloatingActionButtons.js

```
export default function FloatingActionButtons({ azubi }) {
  <Typography gutterBottom>{azubi.name}</Typography>
}
```

Plan.js

```
export default class Plan {
    constructor(name, image, abteilung, bereich, azubis) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.abteilung = abteilung;
        this.bereich = bereich;
        this.azubis = azubis;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you create a demo on codesandbox that reproduces this problem and share the link?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-grass-bwq69?file=/src/FloatingButton.jsx) attempting to recreate your issue and it appears to be fine. Please compare to your own and check for any syntax issues: for example, your *FloatingActionButtons.js* snippet doesn't have a `return` keyword however the error you're getting doesn't match up with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippet the code must work fine. Make sure you're not missing any value while updating the components. Here is the working snippet based on your code:

```js
class Plan {
  constructor(name, image, abteilung, bereich, azubis) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.abteilung = abteilung;
    this.bereich = bereich;
    this.azubis = azubis;
  }
}

function Card() {
  const plan = new Plan("Max Mustermann", "woamen.jpg", "ITH/A", "IT", 13);

  return (<FloatingButton azubi={plan} />);
}

function FloatingButton({
  azubi
}) { 
return (<p> {azubi.name}</p>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Emani it's kinda, because i can see in the browser Debugger that the FloatingButton Component is getting the property as Object. Just the attribute from the Object like name, abteilung etc. Is throwing the error code as i descripted above